# Java:import parent level package

Tags: java, import, package

two package:
`a.sub.ClassA`,
`b.ClassB`;

package a and package b are at the same level in my project.

If I want to use ClassB in ClassA, I wrote `import b.*` in `ClassA`, why does it can't be compiled?

[image: This is my package image:]

This is my code:
bussinessLogicService/MemberBLService.java

```
package bussinessLogicService;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import po.*;

public interface MemberBLService {
    public String getMemberName();
    public String getMemberID();
    //some methods more
}
```

busssinessService/MemberService.java

```
package bussinessLogic.controller;

import java.util.*;
import bussinessLogicService.MemberBLService;

public class MemberBLService_Stub{


}
```

Here is the problem:
[image: See,line 4 can't get compiled!]

Comment: It should work. Can you provide sample code and error.

Comment: What do you mean by same level? Is there anything above "a"? Otherwise `import b.*` should have made ClassB visible (if it is public). What compile error are you getting?

Comment: can you give the specific error you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons for why it could fail. Make sure that

1. file `ClassA.java` is located in folder `./a/sub` and file `ClassB.java` is located in folder `./b`
2. the first line in `ClassA.java` is `package a.sub;`, the first line in the other file is `package b;`
3. both classes are declared as `public` (like: `public class ClassA`)
4. the import statement is written like: `import b.*;` (`import b.ClassB;` should work too)
5. `ClassB` gets compiled *before* `ClassA` (compiler needs to see `./b/ClassB.class`)

Comment: @Andreas.. Well they are not just a `couple` of reasons. They are 5 possible reasons. ;)

Comment: Yeah depending upon what OP is doing. :)

Comment: I have amplified my problem. Could you explain what's wrong?

Comment: Do you build automatically? Try a clean project/build. It all looks pretty normal to me. What's the error message at the marker?

Comment: I started a new clean project. This problem didn't appear. . This project was shared by svn. My teamer didn't come into this problem. I am so confused!

Comment: blame eclipse for that. And if strange things happen again, especially with error markers: simply clean the project. That eliminates 95% of all such issues.

Comment: I deleted the project and then checked out again from svn. Everything became fine! Thank you all the same!!